# Integral Expression Without $dx$, $dy$, $d\tau$, etc.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, notation, taylor-expansion, proof-explanation

My textbook gives the following proof of the single-variable version of Taylor's theorem:

> As promised, we begin with the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, written in the form
>
> $$f(x_0 + h) = f(x_0) + \int_{x_0}^{x_0 + h} f'(\tau) \ d \tau$$
>
> Next, we write $d \tau = - d(x_0 + h - \tau)$ and integrate parts to give
>
> $$f(x_0 + h) = f(x_0) = f'(x_0) h + \int_{x_0}^{x_0 + h} f''(\tau)(x_0 + h - \tau) \ d \tau,$$
>
> which is the first-order Taylor formula. Integrating by parts again, we get
>
> $$\int_{x_0}^{x_0 + h} f''(\tau)(x_0 + h - \tau) \ d\tau = - \dfrac{1}{2} \int_{x_0}^{x_0 + h} f''(\tau) d(x_0 + h - \tau)^2$$
>
> $$= \dfrac{1}{2} f''(x_0) h^2 + \dfrac{1}{2} \int_{x_0}^{x_0 + h} f'''(\tau)(x_0 + h - \tau)^2 \ d \tau,$$
>
> which, when substituted into the preceding formula, gives the **second-order Taylor formula**:
>
> $$f(x_0 + h) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0) h + \dfrac{1}{2}f''(x_0) h^2 + \dfrac{1}{2} \int_{x_0}^{x_0 + h} f'''(\tau)(x_0 + h - \tau)^2 \ \ d\tau$$

I'm confused by the expression

$$- \dfrac{1}{2} \int_{x_0}^{x_0 + h} f''(\tau) d(x_0 + h - \tau)^2$$

Can someone explain what this means when the integral is without a $dx$, $dy$, $d\tau$, etc.? Is such a thing even a valid integral expression? And if there is no $d\tau$, then how are we supposed to know what we integrate the integrand with respect to?

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could please take the time to explain this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can safely ignore it, but what it means is:
$$
\int_{x_0}^{x_0 + h} f''(\tau)(x_0 + h - \tau)d\tau = -\frac{1}{2}\int_{x_0}^{x_0 + h}f''(\tau)\frac{d}{d\tau}(x_0 + h - \tau)^2\; d\tau.
$$
Given that (I hate this:) "the $d\tau$'s cancel", they have written the right-hand side above without either $d\tau$.

Comment: Ahh, ok, that makes sense. Thanks for the clarification!